# Mongodb Connection string

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, connection-string, econnreset

I am new to mongoDB and I have a lot of difficulty with connection strings.

I want to connect to python, so I need a connection string. I came up with this :

```
mongodb://root:pass@localhost/Voice
```

And I get

```
 read ECONNRESET
```

While installing, I installed MongoDB as a service, if that matters. And "Voice" is the name of the database.

Please help

Comment: Are you able to connect to the server from the `mongo` shell?

Comment: Yes sir. I can do all querying;inserting and deleting from the shell, if that's what you mean

Comment: Here is another example of using the connection string the same as yours: [Connection String URI Format Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/connection-string/index.html#records-database).

Comment: econnreset indicates network connectivity issues in your environment.

Comment: Connecting using PyMongo specifying the default database in the connection uri: [Example](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/authentication.html#default-database-and-authsource).